# How do I sum up the numbers in a tuple, thats in a list?

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following list of tuples:
`[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]`

I would like to get the total sum (or other operation_ of all the numbers in each tuple, then get the sum of the entire list.

Desired outcome:

- addition: `1+2+3+(1+2)+(1+3)+(2+3)+(1+2+3) = 24`
- multiplication: `1+2+3+(1×2)+(1×3)+(2×3)+(1×2×3)=23`
- bit operator: `1+2+3+(1⊕2)+(1⊕3)+(2⊕3)+(1⊕2⊕3)=1+2+3+3+2+1+0 = 12.`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried so far, and any problems it has.

Comment: The empty product has value 1, so your multiplication result is wrong. (The other two happen to be correct, but you should still include their zeros.)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by iterating through your list, applying your desired operation, then take the sum:

```py
>> import math
>> from operator import xor
>> from functools import reduce

>> my_values = [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

# Addition
>> addition_values = [sum(x) for x in my_values]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>> sum(addition_values)
24

# Multiplication
>> multiplication_value = [math.prod(x) for x in my_values]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 6]

>> sum(multiplication_value)
24

# Bit operation
>> xor_value = [reduce(xor, x) for x in my_values if x]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]

>> sum(xor_value)
12
```

**You could put this together as a single function:**
*Especially helpful if you want to extend functionality to additional operators...*

```py
import math
from operator import xor, mul, add
from functools import reduce
from typing import List, Tuple, Literal

def operator_then_sum(my_list: List[Tuple], op: Literal[add, mul, xor]) -> int:
    """
    Performs operation on tuples within list
    then returns the total sum of the list

    Args:
       my_list: list of tuples to perform operator on
       op: an operator
    """ 
    
    operated_values = [reduce(op, x) for x in my_values if x]
    return sum(operated_values)

# Test it out on your values
my_values = [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]

>> operator_then_sum(my_values, add)
24
>> operator_then_sum(my_values, mul)
23
>> operator_then_sum(my_values, xor)
12
```

Comment: this is fine, you could enhance it by adding `and_` and `or_` to the `Literal`, in order to handle all associative mathematical operators (the only ones that make sense)

Comment: Understood. Certainly, this function is a template and can be extended to an individual programmer's needs @WalterTross

Answer (score -1):

For the additions, you can apply the sum() function to each element of the list and sum() again on the result.

It can be done on a single line with map():

```
additions = sum(map(sum,tupleList))
```

For the other operations, it would be a bit more subtle because there is no buil-in equivalent to the sum() function for them in Python. They also don't have a universally defined result for single-element or no-element tuples.  You would need to implement those in a function of your own.

For example:

```
def multiply(T):
    if not T: return 0
    return T[0] * multiply(T[1:])

multiplications = sum(map(multiply,tupleList))

def bitXOR(T):
    if len(T) < 2: return T[0] if T else 0
    return T[0] ^ bitXOR(T[1:])

bitOperations = sum(map(bitXOR,tupleList))
```

You could use reduce from functools, but that would still require defining an appropriate default value for empty tuples (which doesn't make it any simpler IMHO) or exclude the empty tuples from the process:

```
from functools import reduce

multiplications = sum( reduce(lambda a,b:a*b,t,bool(t)) for t in tupleList)

from operator import mul as multiply

multiplications = sum(reduce(multiply,t) for t in tupleList if t)

from operator import xor

bitOperations = sum( reduce(xor,t) for t in tupleList if t)
```

As [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) pointed out, with Python 3.8+ there is a prod() function in the math module that is the multiplication equivalent of sum().  But you won't be able to use it directly with map() for your specific use case because the start value would need to vary for empty/non-empty tuples in order to obtain the expected results. However, you can use a comprehension:

```
import math

sum(map(math.prod,tupleList)) # --> 24

sum(math.prod(t,start=bool(t)) for t in tupleList) # --> 23
sum(math.prod(t or [0]) for t in tupleList)        # --> 23
sum(math.prod(t) for t in tupleList if t)          # --> 23
```

or you could filter out the empty tuples and still use map()

```
sum(map(math.prod,filter(None,tupleList))) # --> 23
```

Comment: It's not quite true that the other functions don't have implementations. You could use reduce along with the appropriate operators from the operator module

Comment: Not quite false either since using reduce is not the same has having a built-in prod() function.

Comment: You mean like https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod

Comment: I'm only using Python 3.7 and wasn't aware of math.prod(). I stand corrected and TIL.